# onKey onKeyDown not working

Tags: android

I'm trying to register directional pad / tv remote d pad clicks in my android app. I'm currently testing with the android emulator and I'm trying to click with the directional pad input under the extra settings menu. But I'm not sure why this doesn't work - any help would be appreciated

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private View mContentView;
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

            mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

            mContentView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    Log.d("debug", "we are here");
                    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {
                            Log.d("keycode", "center pressed");
                            return true;
                        }
                    switch (keyCode) {
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
                        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
                            Log.d("OnKey", "key pressed!");
                            return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
}
```

running this code gives me no output whatsoever on logcat

Comment: isyour listener getting called

Comment: @siddhesh I'm really new to android and java so I'm not sure what you mean - what I have above is the only code I'm using. I don't get anything printed out including the first "we are here" line inside the onKey method

Comment: in logcat are you getting this text printed debug", "we are here" or Log.d("keycode", "center pressed");

Comment: @siddhesh nope not getting anything

Comment: what is this mContentView

Comment: Have you tried testing with ADB commands to see if they properly fire the Keyevent code? http://stackoverflow.com/a/30251752/967131

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override onKeyDown() method of your activity to detect key press.

Try this

```
 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

        switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
            case  KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
                 showToast("UP pressed");
            return true;
            case  KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
                 showToast("DOWN pressed");
            return true;
            case  KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
                 showToast("RIGHT pressed");
            return true;
            case  KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
                 showToast("LEFT pressed");
            return true;
            case  KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
                 showToast("CENTER pressed");
            return true;
           }
         }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }

  void showToast(String msg)
  {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),msg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Comment: so do I not need to register a onkeylistener to my mcontentview? can you please explain why this is?

Comment: If you want to provide navigation between views and if you want to access keypress event throughout the activity you can use onKeyDown() method.
View.OnKeyListener can be used for a key event that dispatched to that view only.